# Only sent auto reports when there is data in the report

Tags: email, sharepoint, ssrs-2008, report

I have a report on `SharePoint` that I want to set up to send daily. The problem is that sometimes this report will have no data in it.

So my question is, is it possible to set it up so it only sends out the report if there is data in it?

Comment: How do you plan to send it?
If you code your own way, you can check the content and see if there is data, no?

Comment: It'll be on an automatic schedule that will be sent out daily at 10 in the morning.

Comment: I mean, how do you configure that? I don t know sharepoint, so I don t know how it work. Is it a option in the software that send the report? Is the report writed in a file on the computer and you made a script or IDKW that start with a cron to send it ?

Comment: You deploy the report through SSRS onto the sharepoint server. The you access the report through the website and set up "e-mail subscriptions". The subscription will send the report in question to a list of people that you supply, along with an e-mail body on the schedule you input. I'm not entirely familiar with it myself either.

Comment: So it s in a already existent code. Do you have access to the source? Search where the report is sent, and add something like "if (content != '') {/*send report*/}"